# When should Thread Dumps be taken for a JVM

Tags: java, jvm, thread-dump, jstack

I was reading about the concepts of `Thread Dumps` and found various ways to take Thread Dumps but no articles have mentioned on what basis/issues/reasons the dumps should be taken. We perform a load test on a particular server targeting a JVM and take the Thread Dumps when we observe high CPU utilization or hogging threads. Is this correct ? Can someone throw some light on the reasons on when Thread Dumps should be taken normally or during any load tests.

We use the `jstack` command to capture the dump:

```
/app/jdk/jdk1.7.0_111/bin/jstack -l <ProcessID> > <PathToSaveTheFile>
```

TIA.

Comment: What alternative are you considering?

Answer (score 1):

Thread dumps are used for post-mortem debugging. IMO, what you are doing is right. I don't see a reason for taking a dump in normal conditions.

Comment: thanks, apart from hogging threads and high CPU, are there any other factors to be looked into before considering taking a thread dump ?

Comment: In general there are only three resources that need monitoring: processes/threads, cpu usage and memory. For heap monitoring, jstat is a better tool and you may want to run that also when you face issues.

Answer (score 0):

### <s>Non-</s> Less invasive debugging

You can do thread dumps whenever you see fit to analyse anything to do with thread lock contention, deadlock detection, system resource contention, ...

This is why there are tools to facilitate thread dump whenever we see fit, not only after a JVM crash. Analysis of multiple dumps over time paints fuller picture, than the last crash dump.

This means you can perform **less invasive thread debugging** without attaching a profiler, which in most cases slows down (and possibly alters some dynamic properties) of the application execution.